# AIO in Netty 4.0.0.CR9

Tags: java, netty, nio, aio

I am currently Porting my Netty Server to Version 4 (4.0.0.CR9).

While everything works so far I would also like to try out the performance benefits of the new java7 nio2 implementation. But it seems that the required classes like AioEventLoopGroup etc. are not inside the netty-all or other packages downloaded with the netty bundle.

Has the NIO2 Support been removed from Netty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it has bee removed as it was not any faster then nio.

Comment: I'm working on a project using AIO instead of NIO because actually AIO provides basically much better performance under windows. NIO is just a cheap wrapper around readiness APIs like select, epoll, kqueue. As everybody know windows' select ist rubbish, on windows you have to use IOCP which does not fit well into a selector based API. Also AIO supports async file, it would have been very nice to treat files as channels and to compose them with socket channels. But no AIO in netty =(

Comment: Look at node.js, C# .Net, Golang etc, the call-me-on-finished APIs are a much better abstraction if you want to be truly platform independent.